# how to exporting data from data table to .csv formate

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I am trying to export some data from datatable to .csv file. But the data are not coming to the .csv file its coming as a blank file

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a screenshot. Step through the code to determine where it ends up and what it does write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [StreamWriter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter) should be closed to have the data written to its internal buffer flushed to the file.

So you really need to enclose the creation of the `StreamWriter` inside a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).
The using statement manages the closing of the file and releases the system resource (the file handle). All this happens automatically when you reach the closing brace at the end of the using block ALSO in case of exceptions.

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\report.csv"))
{

    ... all the code that read the datatable and write in the stream....


} // here you get: sw.Flush(); sw.Close(); sw.Dispose();
```

It seems also that you append a comma at the end of each line also for the last column.
Inside the loop the line

```
if(i != dt.Columns.Count)
```

is never false because you exit from the loop when the variable `i` reaches the dt.Columns.Count value. Change it to

```
if(i < dt.Columns.Count-1)
```